# If an enumerated attribute is an attribute that has a fixed set of possible values, what would be an example of a not enumerated attribute in HTML?

Tags: html, attributes

Trying to understand the concept of being 'enumerated' as it pertains to global HTML attributes.

Conceptual question.

Answer (score 0):

An enumerated attribute is basically an attribute with a fixed set of acceptable values. For eg, the *type* attribute for an `<input>` tag can have one of the following values:

1. button
2. checkbox
3. color
4. date
5. email
6. text
7. password

There are quite a few more, but you get the idea. There are a set number of values that this attribute can have. If I were to enter an attribute that was not a part of this pre-defined list, the input button would not know what to do with it, and fallback to its default behavior, which would be an input of type 'text'

eg:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="date">
  <input type="range">
  <input type="list">
</div>
```

As you can see, *list* is not an accepted value, so that input works as a regular text input.

Now if an enumerated attribute can accept only fixed values, by that logic, an attribute that can accept *any* value will not be enumerated. Examples for this could be the **title**, **placeholder**, **data-*** and **value** attributes. There are probably quite a few more, but these are the ones I could think of off the top of my head.

Using the previous example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" title="No file chosen">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Type some text">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something here">
  <input type="date" title="Select a date">
</div>
```

I've given both the placeholder and the title attributes different values, but they're both valid.

Hope this answers your question